# Get the 2nd column records from the csv file when i pass 1st column as a input to the function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
def getprikey(tables):     
   list_pdf= pd.read_csv("s3://test.csv",sep=",")
   for ind in list_pdf.index:
       li_tables = list_pdf['table-name'][ind].lower()
       pkey = list_pdf['marks'][ind].lower()
       print(li_tables)
       print(marks)
      return marks

res = getprikey("naveen")
print(res)
```

I have a csv file which has 2 columns with student marks(1st column as name, 2nd column as marks)I have to write a function to fetch the marks when I pass student name as parameter to the function. I am new to python,Can anybody help plz.

Comment: Where have you found `pd.read_csv("header",True).csv("s3://test.csv")`? Please, read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) first.

Comment: I was reading the csv using spark and converting to pandas dataframe. Updated the code. Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are many things that are wrong with this code. For instance there is no method 'toPandas()' for a DataFrame object

Comment: how can you ensure that the student name is unique ?  what if multiple students have the same name ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Pandas you should avoid iterating over the rows of the dataframe using instead dataframe methods.

To find the items matching a particular criteria you could use the `.loc[]` property.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
marks = df.loc[df['table-name'].str.lower() == 'naveen', 'marks'].values[0]
print(marks)
```